# React Native Android release build crashes after integrating react-native-marketingcloudsdk

Tags: android, react-native, salesforce-marketing-cloud

`react-native-marketingcloudsdk 8.0.0`

It crashes at the startup, and from Crashlytics the crash is reported as follows:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{gbis.gbandroid/gbis.gbandroid.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Requested enabled DevSupportManager, but BridgeDevSupportManager class was not found or could not be created
```

It happens on release build only, but runs well on debug build.

I searched online but didn't find exactly the same crash with `BridgeDevSupportManager` .

And I didn't find a place to report an issue at [salesforce-marketingcloud's GitHub repo](https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/react-native-marketingcloudsdk), which seems not to be open to issue reports.

Not sure if anyone else have run into the same issue and any solution?

Comment: Please create a support case.